# Jackson pendant for GsonFactory?

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson

I use `AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder()` where one of its parameters is a `new GsonFactory()`.

Since I already use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) libs in my code, I do NOT want to use Gson additionally. I would like to solve all my issues with jackson.

So how could I replace the new GsonFactory() parameter with a jackson pendant?

Comment: What is a pendant? You mean parameter?

Comment: @cricket_007 pendant == similar functionality with Jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory`](http://www.massapi.com/class/com/google/api/client/json/jackson/JacksonFactory.html)

Code snippet

```
public void testCredentialCreatedListener() throws IOException {
    MyCredentialCreatedListener listener = new MyCredentialCreatedListener();
    AuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new AuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(BearerToken.queryParameterAccessMethod(),
            new AccessTokenTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            TOKEN_SERVER_URL,
            new BasicAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET),
            CLIENT_ID,
            "authorizationServerEncodedUrl").setCredentialCreatedListener(listener).build();
    assertFalse(listener.called);
```

Comment: Will this with 'jackson2' apply as well? import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;